# How to dereference Mac OS X alias?

Tags: mac-osx, scp, alias

I'm trying to `scp` a file with it's alias. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making symlinks instead of aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried scp with -E flag?

Comment: An alias is *not* the same as a symlink, and it will break with this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `osascript` command to run an AppleScript that dereferences the alias and returns the path to the original.